# Debug Application with MonoDroid Trial Version

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have installad MonoDroid Trial Version.
I have create an "Hello Wolrld" application and debug it in the emulator
but any application appears in the list of application on Android Device Emulator!

The problem is the trial version or some error in my application?

Can you help me please???

Answer (score 3):

The Android emulator is somewhat tricky, at least with MonoDroid. Once you execute the application and have selected the virtual device you defined for Monodroid the emulator will launch. Here comes the tricky part, you'll also get a Monodroid "Select Device" window underneath with some slight differences to what you initially had. You should go to that windows and now choose, for example, "emulator-5554" in the running devices list and press "OK". Once you have done that the application should be deployed to the emulator. Slow but it should be deployed.

For increasing Android emulator performance I recommend you to have a look at [Emulator snapshots](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots) and [this article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBsQFjAB&url=http://morewally.com/cs/blogs/wallym/archive/2011/03/11/android-emulator-increasing-performance-suggestions-for-monodroid.aspx&rct=j&q=morewally%20android%20emulator&ei=KuLwTd7yKdSZhQeoqOkq&usg=AFQjCNHy4WBCFN-55AmF0FSjZBn46_2s7Q&cad=rja) at [MoreWally.com](http://morewally.com).

Answer (score 1):

The bug is described in the following document:

http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/141157-ide-does-not-display-target-device

The procedure I use when starting up is:

1. Close development environment, SDK manager and emulated devices.
2. Open AVD Manager and start the emulator(s) you would like to use.
3. Run the command 'adb devices' (located in Android\android-sdk\platform-tools) and note which devices are listed.
4. If there are none, or the list is incomplete, then run 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server'.  You may wish to create a batch file with these commands.
5. Now check the devices are visible with the command 'adb devices'.
6. Open development environment and everything should work.

If you kill or start a new emulated device, when you have VS2010 open, and then devices do not appear as a 'running device' in VS2010, then close VS2010 and perform steps 4 through 6.  When you reopen it should now work.