# Problem deploying to emulator

Tags: android, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I'm experimenting for the first time, the Mono framework to develop applications to Android.

I have installed Mono for Mac 2.10.2, MonoDevelop 2.6 Beta 3 and the trial version of MonoDroid.

I followed the tutorial for HelloWorld, however I'm having troubles when trying to deploy the application to the emulator.
I click 'Debug', and the 'Select Device' window appears. It shows me my AVD images, and on the bottom of each one it says 'not started'. I select the AVD I want, I click on 'Start Emulator' and the emulator starts. The problem is that it never refreshes to state that the emulator is now running and that I can now deploy the app to it.
If I click 'refresh' the list becomes empty.

Anyone can help me out? Is it something I'm doing wrong or is it a bug of MonoDevelop?
Thanks for your patience ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono 2.10.2 has a bug that prevents MonoDevelop communicating with Android devices. Downgrade to Mono 2.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found it a little bit difficult to figure out how to get my first application working.[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276984/debug-application-with-monodroid-trial-version/6295124#6295124) what I had to do. This was in a Windows system though. I don't know if Mac works in the same way.